# Why my validation using setOnFocusChangeListener isn't working?

Tags: android, validation, kotlin

I wanted to make a validation that whenever the user leaves the TextInputLayout empty and tries to click somewhere else, an error should appear such as "This field can't be empty".
I tried doing like this but yet it isn't working:

```
   fun TextInputLayout.emptyItem() {
    this.editText?.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (!hasFocus) {
            if (this.editText?.text?.trim().isNullOrEmpty()) {
                putError(context.getString(R.string.error_field_obrigatory_message))
            } else {
                this.error = null
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_Input_Valor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                    android:hint="@string/credito_inform_the_value"
                    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme.ClearButton"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/valor"
                        style="@style/TextInputEditTextTheme"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

putError method:

```
fun TextInputLayout.putError(message: String) {
    //prevent a bug from component when setError is called 2 times, message error layout show cutted
    this.error = null
    this.error = message
}
```

Comment: put the putError() method

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve a string resource by using `resources` from an `Activity` instance.
Try to change your `emptyItem` code like this:

```
fun TextInputLayout.emptyItem() {
    this.editText?.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (!hasFocus) {
            val stringValue = this.editText?.text?.trim() ?: ""
            if (stringValue == "") {
                putError(activity.resources.getString(R.string.error_field_obrigatory_message))
            } else {
                this.error = null
            }
        }
    }
```